# Sparklyr not connecting to my hive warehouse

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn, sparklyr

I'm doing a very silly thing and trying to install a Yarn/Hive/Spark/R platform from scratch, not using Hortonworks or Cloudera. I've gotten many pieces figured out but am stuck trying to get my sparklyr to connect to my Hive warehouse.

I am using Rstudio on one machine and connecting to `yarn-client` located on a separate cluster. I've put `hive-site.xml` pretty much everywhere, the local `$SPARK_HOME/conf` and each of the hadoop nodes' `$SPARK_HOME/conf` and `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR`. In `hive-site.xml` I've included the param:

```
  <property>
    <name>spark.sql.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>hdfs://<driver node>/user/hive/warehouse/</value>
    <description>The loation of the hive warehouse</description>
 </property>
```

I feel that that should make it *pretty* clear that I'm trying to use hive but when I run this code:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "CREATE DATABASE test")
DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "use test")
iris_spark_table <- copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite = TRUE)
sdf_copy_to(sc, iris_spark_table)
DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "create table iris_hive as SELECT * FROM iris_spark_table")
```

I get this error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: 
  java.io.IOException: 
    Mkdirs failed to create file:/<my-r-code's-working-dir>/spark-warehouse/test.db/iris_hive/.hive-staging_hive_2018-08-05_14-18-58_646_6160231583951115949-1/-ext-10000/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20180805141859_0013_m_000000_3 
    (exists=false, cwd=file:/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/dzafar/appcache/application_1533357216333_0015/container_1533357216333_0015_01_000002)
```

What am I missing??? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

First of all Spark specific properties should be placed in Spark configuration files. It means you should put

```
spark.sql.warehouse.dir
```

in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`

Additionally you might have a problem with `hdfs-site.xml` not being present on the search path.

Comment: Thanks! If I'm using `spark_connect("yarn-client")`, would I put this on my local spark's conf file or on the yarn driver node's spark conf file?

Comment: So, I've put `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` into the `spark-defaults.conf` files on both local and yarn driver nodes. Then I ensured `hdfs-site.xml` was in both `$SPARK_HOME/conf` and `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` on all yarn nodes. Still no dice. What's going on?

Comment: What is the search path in this case? Somehow it haven't put it in there right?

Comment: @Zafar Take a look at  [Inheriting Hadoop Cluster Configuratio](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#inheriting-hadoop-cluster-configuration) and [Custom Hadoop/Hive Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration)